# Proving $j$-invariant is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, modular-forms

I'm trying to solve exercise $1.1.9$ from Diamond's *A First Course in Modular Forms*, in which we must prove the $j$-invariant $j:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ with  $j(\tau)=1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{\Delta(\tau)}$ is surjective.

The author gives the following suggestion: suppose $\exists\,c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $j^{-1}(c)=\emptyset$. Consider the integral $I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{j'(\tau)}{j(\tau)-c}dz$, where $\gamma$ is described below :

[image]

(the lower segment is an arc of the unit circle and the upper horizontal line has height $>1$)

By the argument principle, $I=0$. Exploring the $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-invariance of $j$, we conclude that the contribution of the two vertical lines cancel each other out (by invariance under $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$). Furthermore, the contribution of left and right sides of the lower arc also cancel each other (by invariance under $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$).

For the horizontal piece, he suggests us the change variables $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, remembering that $j(\tau)=\frac{1}{q}+h(q)$, where $h$ is holomorphic, to conclude the integral equals $1$.

The only part I'm struggling with is the last paragraph. By my computations, $dq =(2\pi i)q\,d\tau$, so:
\begin{align*}
\frac{j'(\tau)}{j(\tau)-c}d\tau &=\frac{-\frac{2\pi i}{q}+(2\pi i)q\,h'(q)}{-c+\frac{1}{q}+h(q)}\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{dq}{q}\\
&=\frac{-\frac{1}{q^2}+h'(q)}{-c+\frac{1}{q}+h(q)}dq\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{q}+\widetilde{h}(q)\right)dq,\,\,\text{ where }\widetilde{h}\text{ is holomorphic} 
\end{align*}

I don't know what to do with this and how I'm supposed to get $1$ from the integral.

Comment: The value $1$ of the upper integral is because $\frac{j'}{j-c} = \frac{-q^{-2}+O(1)}{q^{-1}+O(1)} = -q^{-1} + O(1)$ and $\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{|q|= r} (-q^{-1}+O(1))dq = -2i\pi$.
Alternatively if you already know that $j(i\infty) = \infty$ then $j$ is holomorphic non-constant map of compact Riemann surfaces $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \setminus \mathcal{H}^* \to \Bbb{C}\cup \infty$ so it must be surjective, and since $j(i\infty) = \infty$ it must be surjective $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \setminus \mathcal{H}\to \Bbb{C}$, a point $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\tau$ of the latter representing an isomorphism class of complex tori.

Comment: The image of $j : SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \setminus \mathcal{H}^* \to \Bbb{C}\cup \infty$ is open by analyticity or open mapping theorem and it is closed by compactness, thus it is the whole of $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$

Comment: @reuns, your $O(1)$ is just a holomorphic function of $q$, right? In that case, can't we just say $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|q|=r}\left(-\frac{1}{q}+O(1)\right)dq=\text{Res}_{q=0}\left(-\frac{1}{q}\right)=-1$ for any $r$? I can't see why we need $r\to 0$. Besides, shouldn't we get $I=-1$ instead of $I=1$?

Comment: By the way, the Riemann surfaces argument was pretty neat